# Correlation of stopping times for integral of Brownian motion increment

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\mu(x):=\int_{\epsilon}^{x}\exp\{B_{s+\epsilon}-B_{s-\epsilon}\}ds$, where $(B_{s})_{s\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion (starting at $B_{0}=0$) and epsilon is small $0<\epsilon\ll 1 $. Consider the stopping time

$$T_{a}:=\inf\{t\geq \epsilon: \mu(t)\geq a \},\text{ for $a\geq 0$.}$$

For "good" deterministic choices $a<b<c<d<$ and $t_{1},t_{2}\geq 0$ we are studying the correlation of

$$\{T_{b}-T_{a}\geq t_{1}\}\text{ and }\{T_{d}-T_{c}\geq t_{2}\}.$$

> Q: One approach is by studying a mixing condition: trying to estimate the difference

$$| P[\{T_{d}-T_{c}\geq t_{2}, T_{b}-T_{a}\geq t_{1}\}]-P[\{T_{d}-T_{c}\geq t_{2}\} ]\cdot P[ \{T_{b}-T_{a}\geq t_{1}\}]|$$
when $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ are distant enough.  In other words, we are trying to find **whether** there are any constraints on $a<b<c<d$ so that the above difference goes to zero as the distance $c-b$ between the two intervals increases.

If you think this question is ill-posed or too obvious for Mathoverflow, please put your hint in the comments and I will modify/delete the question.

*Approach*

The process $\mu(x)$ is not Markov because of the $B_{s-\epsilon}$ term and so strong Markov property (SMP) doesn't apply. But in the spirit of (SMP), we introduce the event

$$ E:=\{T_{c}> T_{b}+2\epsilon\}.$$

So just for the sake of understanding (even if we can't get a good control on $E^{c}$), lets focus on the above difference with the first term intersected with $E$:
$$| P[\{T_{d}-T_{c}\geq t_{2}, T_{b}-T_{a}\geq t_{1}\}\cap E]-P[\{T_{d}-T_{c}\geq t_{2}\} ]\cdot P[ \{T_{b}-T_{a}\geq t_{1}]|.$$

Equivalently, by conditioning we are trying to estimate

$$| P[\{T_{d}-T_{c}\geq t_{2}\}\cap E\mid \{T_{b}-T_{a}\geq t_{1}\}]-P[\{T_{d}-T_{c}\geq t_{2}\} ]|.$$

I will update as I find things.